# Is there a possibility to manipulate the raw http-stream from within apache tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, httprequest

An application which consumes my webservice sends an invalid soap-request, my service can not handle this request.

The applications send an wrong tag (misspelled), but they cannot alter this behaviour.

So my question:

Is there a possibility with a filter or a listner to get the raw http stream, alter something and put it back into the chain.

Thank you, Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to change incoming body of the HTTP request. There is no easy way to do this. I don't know of any Servlet API that would allow you to do this "officially".

"Unofficially" you can do some reflection magic on `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request`. If you look at this object, you will see that both methods which return the actual body (`getReader()` and `getInputStream()`) are building streams on top of input buffer, instance of `org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer`. You would have to manipulate that buffer so it returns tainted data.

Needless to say, this is a very volatile and dangerous hack. There are no guarantees this will work on the next Tomcat version (even minor one) and would be virtually unmaintainable.

Comment: I wrote a simple proxy with PHP, there it's quite simple to get the hole http-data stream, manipulate it and put it back into the chain. thank you